# How to add dynamic variable to footer without calling document.newPage() in iText 5

Tags: java, itext, html-to-pdf

The example given in the itext site is working very well.

[Page events for headers and footers](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers)

However, I am creating pdf from list of html strings so I cannot determine when to set `document.newPage()`
If i don't write `document.newPage()`, my `PdfPgeEventHelper` class doesn't update variable on each end of page, instead it gets last updated value.

Main method to create pdf:

```
public static void createPdf(ArrayList<String> htmlStrings, FooterTable footerEvt, String destinationPath)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    document.setMargins(68, 85, 75, 85);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destinationPath));
    if (footerEvt != null)
        writer.setPageEvent(footerEvt);
    document.open();

    CSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    CssFile cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper
            .getCSS(new ByteArrayInputStream(readCSS("resources/content.min.css").getBytes()));
    cssResolver.addCss(cssFile);

    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
    fontProvider.register("resources/ARIAL.TTF");

    CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
    HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);
    htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
    int i = 0;
    for (String htmlfile : htmlStrings) {
        i++;
        footerEvt.setTitleIndex("" + i);//or FooterTable.setTitleIndex("" + i);
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlfile.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        p.parse(stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
    document.close();
}
```

**FooterTable** class which extends **PdfPageEventHelper**

```
public static void setTitleIndex(String _titleIndex) {
    titleIndex = _titleIndex;
}
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    pageNumber = writer.getPageNumber();
    generateFooter().writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(), document.bottom() - getTableHeight(footerTable) + 25,
            writer.getDirectContent());
}
public PdfPTable generateFooter() {
    try {
        BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.createFont("resources/Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        footerTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        footerTable.setTotalWidth(440);
        footerTable.setLockedWidth(true);

        Font pageNumberFont = new Font(baseFont, 9, Font.BOLD);
        Paragraph pageNumberP = new Paragraph(titleIndex+"-"+ pageNumber, pageNumberFont);
        PdfPCell pageNumberCell = new PdfPCell(pageNumberP);
        pageNumberCell.setBorder(0);
        pageNumberCell.setPaddingTop(20);
        footerTable.addCell(pageNumberCell);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return footerTable;
}
```

For example if there are 10 htmlstrings, in footer every titleIndex is written as 11. But pagenumbers are written correctly.

**EXAMPLE OUTPUT:**

First page's footer
[image: First page's footer]

Second page's footer
[image: Second page's footer]

and it continues like that 11-3, 11-4, 11-5 ...

As you can see the variable is not updating each time. It should be 1-1, 2-2, 3-3, 4-4 ...

NOTE: Using iText 5.5.11

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it without newPage in your example.  onEndPage invoked by newPage,I guess.

Comment: @trd3v3lop but how pageNumbers are written correctly. I change the pageNumber variable also in the onEndPage

Comment: The `newPage` with the page event happens also when iText automatically creates a new page.

Comment: @mkl so why not my footer is updated ? if i write `document.newPage()` at the end of the for loop it gets updated

Comment: First of all, the page events obviously are triggered, otherwise you wouldn't get any footers at all. It appears as if either the `p.parse` does not push the parsed elements to the document synchronously (so you would update the title index before the content you assume sent actually is forwarded to the writer) or your remaining code has an error. From the code pieces you shared I cannot tell.

Comment: @mkl added full codes.

Comment: I'm taking a look

Comment: I just ran your code using iText 5.5.11 (except for the files and methods you did not provide) and got page numbers 1-1, 2-2, 2-3,3-4, 3-5, 3-6. Thus, either there is something special in your inputs (html strings or css) or your versions.

Comment: @mkl stange.. does all of your htmls contains <html> tag ?

Comment: None. I used merely 1000 word Lorem Ipsums whose paragraphs were in `<p>`...`</p>`.

Comment: @ayZagen Have you checked whether you have some opening tags without matching closing tags?

Comment: @mkl yeah there are no errors at html